# cmu sphinx java - Executable example code

Tags: java, sphinx4

I recently installed CMU Sphinx4 to use for my Java application requiring speech recognition. However, most of the source code I could find online for Sphinx4 shows some error in Eclipse. I downloaded the JAR files (sphinx4-data..., sphinx4-core...) and added them to my libraries in my build path; however, there are still errors (for example, it cannot recognize the Speech class). Can anyone give me the bare minimum it takes to listen to input and print it onto the console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demos are available in sources:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java

The tutorial describing the API is provided here:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Sphinx4 source code (this includes sample code ) from Sourceforge
2. Compile code using maven.
3. take sphinx4-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar from build.
4. Configure eclipse with sample code.

I configure my eclipse to run Samples as follows:-

```
-libs
   --commons-math3-3.2.jar
   --sphinx4-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   --sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-sphinx4-samples
-bin
-.classpath
-.project
```